# Is there a Java WindowListener that gets called just before a Window is shown?

Tags: java, swing, awt, event-listener

Is there a Java WindowListener that gets called just before a Window is shown?

I've tried both `windowOpened` (example below) and `componentShown`.  Both of these get called just **after** the window is shown.  Is there any listener that gets called **before** the window is shown?

```
window.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent evt) {
        < ... code ... >    
    }
});
```

Comment: Given [the `WindowListener` methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html), no.

Comment: You're the one kicking the show(), so you could fire something, yourself?

Comment: wouldnt an overridden `setVisisble()`/`show()`-method, which invokes your code just before it opens the window, fit your needs?

Comment: Given that there isn't a direct solution, maybe you could add some more information about what you're trying to do, that way we can help you solve that problem. As it stands, it's too vague for us to give you any serious constructive feedback. What if you aren't the one calling `show` or you can't override `setVisible`? We need to know this information. Per your question, @MattBall is correct, there isn't a listener for that.

Comment: Have a look at [`RequestFocusListener`](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/dialog-focus/) which uses an [`AncestorListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/AncestorListener.html).

Comment: That pretty much answers my question then.  I can, in fact, do it before I show the window, but I was trying to avoid that.  I've got some specific code that alters the windows in my application before they're shown.  The options are 1. copy and paste that code for every window (which people always forget to do) or 2. Do it in some central place that has access to all of the windows (which is what I'm trying to do).

Comment: @Luke as per your latest comment, why not create a custom class which extends `JFrame`, override `setVisible(..)` do what you need, remembering to call `super.setVisible(..)`. Alter your code to use your own custom `JFrame` class which already has the implemented functionality if I understood correctly

Comment: @Luke but hierarchy and ancesorlistener returns events asynchronously, have to override isDisplayable for container

Comment: @DavidKroukamp I thought about making my own JFrame subclass but then I'd have to change tons of Net beans UIs from JFrame to MyAwsomeCustomFrame.  I don't know of a non-painful way to do that...

Comment: @AndrewThompson Good idea with the AncestorListener, but sadly it still gets called just **after** the window is displayed.  `WindowListener.windowOpened(...)` is closer to what I want, but it also gets called after the window is displayed.

Comment: @Luke a simple Find and Replace with finding "new JFrame" to "new MySuperAwsomeJFrame" should work out, without taking too long.

Comment: @Zhedar Netbeans UI's all extend `javax.swing.JFrame` and it uses 2 files, a `.java` file and a `.form`.  It's easy enough to change in the `.java` file, but netbeans doesn't allow you to directly edit the `.form`.  You might be able to use an outside tool to safely find/replace all references (even in the `.form` file), but I'm not sure I'd trust that. EDIT - Nevermind, in Netbeans 7.2 apparently the UI Designer is smart enough to update itself.

Comment: @Zhedar Can you make that an official answer.  It looks like that's as close as I'm going to get here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wish here's an answer compiled by the comments.(Maybe sometimes somebody will search for that ;) )
The solution here may to override your `JFrame`'s `setVisible(boolean)`-method by subclassing `JFrame`.

That method could look like this:

```
@Override
public void setVisible(boolean visible)
{
   if(visible) //Window is going to be shown
   {
       //your code you want to be executed before window is shown
   }

   //finally show or hide window
   super.setVisible(visible);
}
```

As in this case you need to refactor your code to use the new subclass, just find and replace every "new JFrame" to "new YourFrameSub"(every editor or IDE should be able to do that).
This way you can ensure your code is executed, **before** anything is shown.
Remember to use a `SwingWorker` or sth. like that to show something like a `ProgressBar` in a `JDialog` to show the user that something will take longer than expected. Of course this only takes place if you're planning to execute a long running action like doing IO-operations.